# How can I access a plugin's user defined options in a public function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin and within it I have a public function ($fn.myplugin.mypublicfunct). My intention is to have mypublicfunct called from a separate .ajaxSuccess outside of myplugin. Thus the want for a public function.

Scenario: myplugin does its thing...form submit via Ajax is different plugin...when that plugin does its .ajaxSuccess I want to call mypublicfunct but be able to use the user options / defaults from myplugin.

Does that make sense? Am I asking the right question the right way?

I tried putting

var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.myplug.defaults, options);

within the public function and got an error for options not defined (or similar). I'm Google searching up a storm looking for an example, solution, etc. and still I got nuttin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll qualify this first by saying that I'm a relative newbie to jQuery plug-in development. Further, this is something I have struggled with myself, so it's a +1 from me for a good question.

What I have tended to do is store my options object on the data property of the selected element (name-spaced with the plugin name):

```
var data = {
    options: options,
    otherData: otherData
};

$(this).data('myPlugin', data);
```

The object is then accessible in the public function like so:

```
var options = $(this).data('myPlugin').options;
```

It feels a bit clunky but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks @net.uk.sweet - Ok, it's a start. So you stash the options in the data property of some element and then grab it. Interesting. None the less, it seems a bit awkward. No offense but let's see what else comes in.

Comment: None taken! I have to say, my experience of plug-in development so far has been that it's all a bit awkward.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't store the data on any old element, I store it on the selected element the plugin is called against. I imagine there are situations where you might have a plugin which is not passed a selector in which case this approach would not work.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have to try this. I think what complicates things is that I'm really calling the plugin, just a public function. That said, my understanding is that such things are what make jquery nice to use. So I expected an obvious solution. Or perhaps it's not jquery? Perhaps I'm blind. Worst case, I'll just pass everything in. It might be better that way regardless. That is nothing will be assumed / implied. You get what you ask for, period. Cheers

Comment: I must say, I'm surprised there haven't been more answers on this. It might be helpful if you posted a fiddle which showed your plugin and the code which interacts with it. I think I know what you're describing, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, I think editing the post bumps it up again so it might receive more attention.

Comment: I agree 100%. That is, my description is ideal / accurate. Catch 22, eh? Ya can't describe something ya don't know :) How about this...I'm writing Plugin A. It has default option values, as well as user defined option value (that override the default). In Plugin A I want to have a public function that can be called from (for example) Plugin B. But I want the function in Plugin A to use the defaults/options when B calls. I don't want B to have to specify anymore than it needs to. I'm trying to implement your sugggestion but seem to be having issues. I've got issues. Who knew ;)

Comment: Yeah that's how I'd interpreted your question. I've spoken to a couple of more experienced jQuery devs here who have both confirmed that this is exactly the approach they use (be nice to see a couple of upvotes from the stack community just to validate this). If you're still having problems, post a fiddle of just your plugin and I'll give it the once over.

Comment: Thanks again. Got it. Works like a charm. btw, I feel your learning it pain. I constantly feel like there are plenty of answers but few optimal, best practices, etc. I hate feeling I could be doing something (that works) but someone else would say "You idiot." I suppose there's no easy way but a few more sign posts along the way certainly couldn't hurt, yes?